# Появления модального окна ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Как вывести модальное окно или всплывающее сообщение. Пробовал модальное окно вывести, но она не закрывается при клике на него.
Нужно, что-то вроде алерта. Подскажите как лучше сделать?

```
<?
if (!$_SESSION['name']) {
echo "<script>alert('Комментарии могут оставлять только зарегистрированные пользователи')</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Обычно это просто заглушка в html.. а не модальные окна и пр. как эти [bootstrap alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/)

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать
https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr
демо
https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html
простие и красиво